# It is possible to access a parameter from an action filter in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, action-filter, custom-action-filter

i have a custom action filter in my mvc 3 web application that performs Logs on a database and i would like to get more information about the Action that is accessing the user so i have this code now:

```
[ActionFilters.ProductStream(Message = "PUBLISH a Product")]
public ActionResult PublishProducts(PublishedContainerVO publishedContainer) {

//some code

}
```

And i would like to do something like this:

```
[ActionFilters.ProductStream(Message = "PUBLISH a Product", Id = publishedContainer.Id)]
public ActionResult PublishProducts(PublishedContainerVO publishedContainer) {

//some code

}
```

Is that possible? I have seen that inside the Action filter i can access that parameters by his key, but in this case... i have a complex object and not a simple id.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because metadata are created at compile time.